# How to design viewfinder for QR scanner for scanning screen?

Tags: android, cordova, qr-code

I have integrated QR Scanner for cordova android app.Currently when scanner opens it just shows video preview and scanning of QR code is fine.But I need to show viewfinder(Box where QR code must be placed to scan).Please help give your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Draw a rectangle using canvas of your preview class #onDraw method. You can always use rectangle coordinates to find QR code.

example: canvas.drawRect

Hope my answer helps